# Assign task to a specific user in Bonita BPM 7.5

Tags: groovy, bonita

I have a process with many tasks that should be done by different users and I don't want to use the bonita predefined actor filters (initiator & initiator-manager)
Is there a way to exactly choose which user can do the task by changing actor mapping or defining a new actor filter?

I tried to add three actors and in configuration--->Actor mapping and chose 1 user for every actor but the problem is that when the specified actor(user) in a step takes the task, after submitting the information in the form there is no option to release the task and let the process to proceed to next task that another actor(user) has to do.
(sorry for poor English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by :

Used Actor filter single User for every task and specified the user ID with a Groovy script Using :
`apiAccessor.identityAPI.getUserByUserName("walter.bates")`

Some other methods of identityAPI can be usefull too.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach to use *actors* and configure *actor mapping* is correct and should provide the result you are expecting.

In a scenario where:

- Step1 is for ActorA and ActorA is mapped to user walter.bates
- Step2 is for ActorB and ActorB is mapped to user helen.kelly

when Walter see the task list it will be able to:

- select the task
- take it: he still needs to take it as potentially group of users or multiple users can be mapped to an actor
- submit the form
- process execution will continue to Step2
- at this point walter.bates doesn't have any task to do and helen.kelly have one task to do.

Once walter.bates submit the form the task is done and no need to release it.

You can [download the basic example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6tsat5meq3kzn6/DemoActorMappingSingleUserDiagram-1.0.bos?dl=0) I create to illustrate this behavior.

Also in your use case I think it might be intersting to use the "single user"  filter so user does not have to take the task. I create [another diagram](https://www.dropbox.com/s/39gt7ea39epbvvc/DemoActorMappingSingleUserFilterDiagram-1.0.bos?dl=0) to illustrate this solution.